# DisableValidator don't work in Swagger-Net

Tags: asp.net, validation, swagger-net

I want to disable validator but it's not work.
I'm in old ASP.Net projet used VB with Nugget Swagger-NET.

This is my swagger config. I try to use DisableValidator and SetValidatorUrl.
[My code with param](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ml3GS.png)

I don't want swagger try to validate model.
I don't want this :
[I don't want this validation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IrCmw.png)

I want to make the call and let my code do validation.

Can you help me ?

Thank you